# How to disable cache in scrapy?

Tags: caching, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a webpage on a particular website.The webpage varies a little for different set of cookies that I sent through `scrapy.Request()`.

If I make the request to webpage one by one , it gives me the correct result, but when I send these cookies in for loop, it is giving me the same result. I think scrapy is creating cache for me and in the second request its taking the response from that cache.Here is my code :

```
def start_requests(self):
        meta = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED':True}
        productUrl = "http://xyz"
        cookies = [{'name': '', 'value': '=='},{'name': '', 'value': '=='}]
        for cook in cookies:

            header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"}
            productResponse = scrapy.Request(productUrl,callback=self.parseResponse,method='GET',meta=meta,body=str(),cookies=[cook],encoding='utf-8',priority=0,dont_filter=True)
            yield productResponse


def parseResponse(self,response): 
     selector = Selector(response)
     print selector.xpath("xpaths here").extract()
     yield None
```

I expect that the print statement should give different result for the two requests.

If anything isn't clear , please mention in comments.

Comment: You can see what cookies are being sent by reviewing `request.headers` for each request.  You will have a `'Cookie':` entry.  It may be that your old Cookies are persisting, as Scrapy keeps a cookiejar per-site for an entire crawl. To disable this, add `'dont_merge_cookies': True'` to your `request.meta`.  See [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) for more details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cache can be disable in 2 ways

1. Changing values in cache related settings in setting.py file. By Keeping HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=False
2. Or it can be done in runtime " scrapy crawl crawl-name --set HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=False

Comment: FWIW, I got an exception with 2. - but it worked with: --set HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=0

Answer (score 6):

Here I assume that you just want to avoid caching only specific requests.

For this example it means avoid caching those requests under `start_requests` and cache all other requests (which you may have under `parseResponse`).

To do this just add `productResponse.meta['dont_cache'] = True` line to your code and
set `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True` under `settings.py`

Now all other requests  will be cached.

```py
def start_requests(self):
    meta = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED':True}
    productUrl = "http://xyz"
    cookies = [{'name': '', 'value': '=='},{'name': '', 'value': '=='}]
    for cook in cookies:
        productResponse = scrapy.Request(productUrl, callback=self.parseResponse, method='GET',
                                         meta=meta, body=str(), cookies=[cook],
                                         encoding='utf-8', priority=0, dont_filter=True)
        productResponse.meta['dont_cache'] = True
        yield productResponse

def parseResponse(self,response): 
        selector = Selector(response)
        print selector.xpath("xpaths here").extract()
        yield None
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a dummy parameter to the request url

```py
import random

productUrl = "http://xyz" + "?dummy=" + str(random.random())
```