# How to refresh a web page with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to open a web page with Chrome and refresh it with python3 in every 10 seconds. I think the selenium way would be something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('mypage.html')

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.refresh()
```

But I want to do it with scrapy. I did a research and could not get any result. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy won't have a refresh feature as such - but you can just embed it in a while loop in the same way that you've made selenium refresh. You might have to [disable the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615250/how-to-disable-cache-in-scrapy) in Scrapy first to prevent it from just sourcing data from reloaded pages from there.